# Rails teaspoon JS Test

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hello i'm following a tutorial for integrate in my Ruby on Rails application Angular JS  [Source](http://angular-rails.com/find_and_browse.html).
I must doing some controller test for the Javascript.

this is my the file **spec/javascripts/controllers/RecipesController_spec.coffee** :

```
describe "RecipesController", ->
  scope        = null
  ctrl         = null
  location     = null
  routeParams  = null
  resource     = null

  setupController =(keywords)->
    inject(($location, $routeParams, $rootScope, $resource, $controller)->
      scope       = $rootScope.$new()
      location    = $location
      resource    = $resource
      routeParams = $routeParams
      routeParams.keywords = keywords

      ctrl        = $controller('RecipesController',
                                $scope: scope
                                $location: location)
    )

  beforeEach(module("receta"))
  beforeEach(setupController())

  it 'defaults to no recipes', ->
    expect(scope.recipes).toEqualData([])
```

this is the Application Angular Controller collocated in **app/assets/javascripts/**:

```
    receta = angular.module('receta',[
  'templates',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'controllers',
])

receta.config([ '$routeProvider',
  ($routeProvider)->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',
        templateUrl: "index.html"
        controller: 'RecipesController'
      )
])

recipes = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'Spaghetti alla Carbonara'
  },
  {
    id: 2
    name: 'Spaghetti alle vongole e cozze'
  },
  {
    id: 3
    name: 'Bistecca'
  },
  {
    id: 4
    name: 'Fritto'
  }
]

controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("RecipesController", [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$resource',
  ($scope,$routeParams,$location,$resource)->
    $scope.search = (keywords)->  $location.path("/").search('keywords',keywords)

    if $routeParams.keywords
      keywords = $routeParams.keywords.toLowerCase()
      $scope.recipes = recipes.filter (recipe)-> recipe.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords) != -1
    else
      $scope.recipes = []
])
```

when i try to execute the tests i recive this error message:

```
  1) RecipesController defaults to no recipes
     Failure/Error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource (line 4263)
```

it cant find the provider, this is my first time that i use teaspoon for testing js.